# Metodo .toPromise deprecated

Tags: angular, promesas

En mi aplicacion angular estoy integrando stripe. En un componente tengo una funcion que hace una llamada al backend para traer desde la api de stripe el paiment_intet. Antes en el servicio que hacia la llamada al back tenia una funcion con .toPromise

El problema es que ahora ya esta en desuso. Ahora lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
      createPaymentMethod (){ 
     return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/pm_method', { 
  
     }) 
   }
```

Y asi lo recibo en mi componente:

```
    const paymentIntent = this._stripeService.createPaymentIntent(token.id, 100, paymentMethod.paymentMethod.id); 
  
     console.log(paymentIntent);
```

El problema es que no consigo acceder al a los valores del objeto, por ejemplo

console.log(paymentIntent.client_secret)

Me da error tdo el tiempo.

Y probado con esto pero no puedo usarlo fuera del then.

```
    let clientSecret: any;
    paymentIntent.then(response => {     
       clientSecret = response['client_secret'];     
     }); 
  
     console.log(clientSecret);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toPromise` puede reemplazarse con `lastValueFrom` o `firstValueFrom`

Ejemplo:

```
(async function () {
  const data = await of('using to promise').toPromise();
  console.log(data);
})();

(async function () {
  const data = await lastValueFrom(of('using last value from'));
  console.log(data);
})();
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-s4suxi?file=index.ts)

[Referencia lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom)